# How to map 「英数」 or 「かな」 key common in the JIS layout of Mac keyboards on vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard, key-bindings, neovim

Okay, please here me out on this -- this question is not about using these keys.

Macs come with a JIS keyboard layout that has the following keys 「英数」 and 「かな」 that is used to switch between Japanese and English input. (image below)

[image: JIS layout]

I would like to use these two keys to toggle between insert, visual, and normal mode. I tried pressing the 英数 and the かな key with Ctr+V in insert mode, but nothing was showing up so I have no clue about what vim sees when these keys are pressed.

Does anyone know how I can map these two keys to visual/insert mode?
If not, I would really appreciate some guidance on at least figuring out what vim sees when these two keys are entered.

Comment: If you don't see anything after that `<C-v>` trick, then it means that Vim can't see those keys, which makes it impossible to map them.

Comment: That ^, but you can always check with gvim (or a gui of neovim or whatever, depending on what you're using) to see if a GUI can intercept it. If it can't, you can't map it in any variant. There's not really a way to work around that without adding a patch to (n,g)vim

Answer (score 1):

my recommendation is using Karabiner 
`https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org` 
You can then map those keys to any key you want. The karabiner-eventviewer can help you find the pressed key easily.
I had a JIS keyboard and map the 英数 to command so my left thumb does not need to stretch too much. Good luck